# Powershell process wait for SQL query to complete

Tags: sql, powershell

I have a Powershell script that runs daily. The script is supposed to run a SQL query and create a file with the results.

```
Import-Module SqlPs
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "C:\SQL Queries\dailyexport1pm.sql" | Out-File -filepath "I:\HTPN Training and Workflow\Daily Epic Completion\$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)dailyexport1pm.txt"
```

This used to work, however we recently added a large amount of data that causes the query to take up to 3.5 minutes. I do not have a strong understanding of powershell and need to have the out-file process run once the SQL query is complete. Any assistance would be appreciated.

The script outputs a blank txt file. When I check the task scheduler last run result, that the powershell script is the only action of, it says "The operation completed successfully. (0x0)"

Comment: Do you get an error? Does it output a blank file, or partial file? What exactly do you need help with?

Comment: Do you need help on the query part? 
Invoke-SqlCmd retrieved all rows into a single DataSet object,as a result, they don't get discarded. Use 'Go' in the sql script in every chunk so that it can split in batches. Explain more about the requirement. Is it output NULL/blank ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there might be some error in the sql-file. Requesting you to try this once:

```
$Error.Clear()
try {

Import-Module SqlPs
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "C:\SQL Queries\dailyexport1pm.sql" -WarningAction SilentlyContinue  -OutputSqlErrors $false
}
 catch {
    $Error | out-file -filepath "C:\temp\SqlLog.txt"
}
```

Note: Later if you see no error and the output is coming properly then you can pipe it to 'Out-File -filepath "I:\HTPN Training and Workflow\Daily Epic Completion\$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)dailyexport1pm.txt" '

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance. I ran the script in powershell and noticed that the script was timing out on the query so I increased the querytimeout .
    Import-Module SqlPs
Invoke-Sqlcmd -InputFile "C:\SQL Queries\dailyexport1pm.sql" -querytimeout 300 | Out-File -filepath "I:\HTPN Training and Workflow\Daily Epic Completion\$(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd)dailyexport1pm.txt"

Comment: Superb @Scott: If the answer helps you then accepting/upvoting it would be appreciable.